# Get roles of page with role based protection

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, user-roles

What's the current alternative to `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.Access.GetAccessingMembershipRoles`? Because umbraco 7.6 highlights it as obsolete and tells to use `IPublicAccessService`

I was unable to find out how to use it though, all I got to was

```
IContent content = GetById(id);
Attempt<PublicAccessEntry> access = _publicAccessService.IsProtected(content);
```

which doesn't have any information about the current page roles.

Comment: See my answer to your question below please @nickornotto and mark it as the correct answer after testing this yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you do it;

```
IContent content = GetById(id);
var publicAccessService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.PublicAccessService;
var entryForContent = publicAccessService.GetEntryForContent(content);
```

You will see that entryForContent result has got Rules and this is what you need. See details below;

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, that's what I was missing. Thanks!